# I can't open JAR files

Tags: java, macos, jar

I have java installed. both JDK and runtime. im kind of new to java. I want to open a .jar file but it is saying that `The operation couldn’t be completed. Failed to execute /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java: No such file or directory`

Im using macOS Monterey. my CPU is I5 and I have a Mac book 2020 and 13 inches. more info: MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2020, Four Thunderbolt 3 ports) processer: 2 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5 memory: 16 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 1536 MB

Comment: How are you trying to open it? Command line? If yes, which command?

Comment: You have to set `jdk/bin` path in `environment variable`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

we can use `jar` command to view or open the jar files.
see the [official docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/view.html), it gives an example:

```
jar tvf xxxxx.jar
```

So check if you provide the **correct path** of jar files.